# How to create an external guard in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I work with a monorepo which includes several NestJS apps, all deployed separately.
An authentication guard is needed to parse JWTs and since it's the same one for all apps, I need to make it "common". My strategy is the following structure:

```
- root
- - packages
- - - app1
- - - app2
- - - guards
- - - - src
- - - - dist
```

The way our company works with monorepos is by building common packages, and importing from `dist`. So the guard I want should be written under `guards/src`, then built and imported from `guards/dist`, so for example:

```
// app1/src/main.ts
import { AuthGuard } from 'guards/dist`;

async function bootstrap() {
  // ...
  app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthGuard());
  // ...
}
```

The issue is as follows:
Following the [NestJS docs for JSW handling](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-the-authentication-guard) I built my guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {}
}
```

But when using it in the above example (in `new AuthGuard()`), I am required to provide the argument `jwtService` which would normally be injected by a module.
But this guard isn't used in a module, nor would I want to include the `JwtService` in every app separately - that defeats the purpose of a common auth guard!

I'm not sure how to target this. The options I see now are:

1. Make `guards` export a module instead of an injectable. (issue: how to implement guards this way?)
2. Skip `JwtService` and use another library for parsing JWTs. (issue: specific solution that doesn't solve future similar issues).
3. Instantiate `JwtService` myself, instead of relying on dependency injection. (issue: defeats Nest's architecture design).

What say you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the [other way to create a global guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#binding-guards) in Nest. You can use the `APP_GUARD` provider in a custom provider in any module in your application and get the guard globally bound. E.g.

```js
@Module({
  imports: AllTheOtherImportsForYourApp,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now, no need for `app.useGlobalGuards()` or anything like that.

This approach works for `APP_PIPE`, `APP_INTERCEPTOR`, and `APP_FILTER` **and** the `APP_*` providers can be used more than once.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this method, but it does not solve the issue where `AuthGuard` requires `JwtService`. In your solution, as I myself mentioned, I would have to add `JwtService` as a provider.

Comment: No, you wouldn't. That's why you use `useClass`, so Nest _knows_ of this class and creates it for you, doing all of the dependency injection you're used to. That's literally why this approach exists

Comment: This is demonstrably incorrect. I just tried what you suggested, and, as expected, Nest complains that `JwtService` is not available in the `AppModule` scope. This means that either way I have to somethow inject or instantiate it.

Comment: Most likely because `JwtService` comes from importing `JwtModule` and your `AuthModule` (which I presume imports `JwtModule` and is imported by `AppModule`) does not make use of module re-exporting by **also** exporting `JwtModule`

Comment: there is no `AuthModule`, only an `AughGuard` which lives on its own. From the Nest docs I got the impression that's the way to do it if all I need is a guard, rather than an entire auth module with extra functionality.

Comment: So where do you import and configure the `JwtModule` to create the `JwtService`?

Comment: That is exactly what the question is about. I don't know. Currently my solution is to manually instantiate `new JwtService()` inside `AuthGuard`.

Comment: Well, wherever you use the `APP_GUARD` approach, add the `JwtModule.register()` into the `imports` of that module and JwtService` will be available

Comment: Well that's exactly my problem, becuase you're asking me to separately do this in every app that uses this guard, I would like to avoid that, hence... the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253224/discussion-between-jay-mcdoniel-and-ronny-efronny).